# Do we have rights to this Patent?

Tags: us7577595

This patten was done by and part of MyOnlyCatalog.com from which Philip Berlin explicitely said it in writing.

Do MyOnlyCatalog share holders get any money if the pantent is sold?

Answer (score 1):

Taking this question as in the vein of "how does the patent system work", that patent can be looked up in google patents, as well as on the patent office recordation site, to see that it was assigned to MyOnlyCataog by the inventors in 2009, then the assignment was reversed in 2010 and the patent was again owned by the inventors.  Most recently, in 2011 the inventors assigned it to TACK FOSS B.V., LLC. The inventors are shown as GRANT, DAVID of CALIFORNIA and BERLIN, PHILLIP of FLORIDA.

What agreements the inventors may or may not have with the various companies and shareholders is a separate issue.